# JSF unable to set dynamic id for input component

Tags: jsf

my form looks like this:

[image]

When the user clicks "+ Add"  a new distance input shows up:

[image]

The user can repeat this operation as many times as desired, but all distances must be filled in, and individual messages must be served for missing data:

[image]

So i'm trying to stablish dynamic ids for the distance inputs. However, when i try to pass dynamic values everything fails. up to now i've tried two different techniques:

- using the binding HtmlDataTable's rowIndex <- it always shows -1
- setting the id as an attribute of the Distance class <- ugly exception

here's my code:

Backing bean:

```
private List<Distance> distances;
private HtmlDataTable distancesUI;

public void addDistance(ActionEvent e) {
    distances.add(new Distance());
}
```

JSPX:

```
<h:dataTable
binding="#{Bean.distancesUI}"   
value="#{Bean.distances}"
var="distance"> 
    <h:column> 
        <h:inputText 
        id ="distance_#{Bean.distancesUI.rowIndex}" // <- always renders "distance_-1"
        value="#{distance.value}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

I need to be able to show individual "required" messages. Any ideas?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I need to be able to show individual "required" messages. Any ideas?*

For that you don't need to fiddle with IDs. JSF will do it for you. Just do

```html
<h:dataTable id="table" value="#{bean.distances}" var="distance"> 
    <h:column> 
        <h:inputText id="distance" value="#{distance.value}" required="true" />
        <h:message for="distance" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

This will end up in generated HTML like follows:

```html
<table id="form:table">
    <tr><td><input id="form:table:0:distance" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input id="form:table:1:distance" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input id="form:table:2:distance" /></td></tr>
    ...
</table>
```

Rightclick the page in browser and choose *View Source* to see it yourself.

Any validation error will just be shown in the same row as the input.