# How to ensure different ids for JSF taglib sub-components?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jstl, facelets, taglib

Let us assume that we have defined the JSF tag lib with following code:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <h:outputLabel for="myid" value="#{label}: " />
        <h:inputText id="myid" value="#{value}" required="true" />
        <h:message for="myid" />
    </h:panelGrid> 

</ui:composition>
```

Then we want to use in some form:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <my:nameEditor value="#{item.firstname}" label="First name" />
    <my:nameEditor value="#{item.lastname}" label="Last name" />
...
</h:form>
```

But instead of getting a reusable editor, the following error is thrown:

> Exception message: Component ID myForm:myid has already been found in the view.

So my question is: how can we ensure that sub-components from different tags will have different ids?

*PS. My wanderings:
I already tried to use variables with dynamic prefixes to ids (e.g. id="#{prefix}myid"), but both `<c:set >` and `<ui:param >` (as well as respective loops) turned out to be useless (as JSTL expressions are set before rendering - so we get the same value for both instances, and there's no scope that would nicely cover only one tag instance; and JSF expressions are set after building components tree so cannot be seen while ids are created).*

*Finally (inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/7312979/2045440) I managed to "make it work" by enclosing taglib content by `<h:dataTable>` with single row, but I'm really not convinced that the following is the prettiest thing we can achieve:*

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:dataTable value="">
        <h:column>
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                <h:outputLabel for="myid" value="#{label}: " />
                <h:inputText id="myid" value="#{value}" required="true" />
                <h:message for="myid" />
            </h:panelGrid> 
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just set the ID as another attribute.

```
<my:nameEditor id="firstname" value="#{item.firstname}" label="First name" />
<my:nameEditor id="lastname" value="#{item.lastname}" label="Last name" />
```

```html
<h:panelGrid columns="3">
    <h:outputLabel for="#{id}" value="#{label}: " />
    <h:inputText id="#{id}" value="#{value}" required="true" />
    <h:message for="#{id}" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

That should just work. An alternative is to wrap it in a naming container like `<f:subview>`.

```html
<f:subview id="#{id}">
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <h:outputLabel for="myid" value="#{label}: " />
        <h:inputText id="myid" value="#{value}" required="true" />
        <h:message for="myid" />
    </h:panelGrid> 
</f:subview>
```

Again another alternative is to convert it to a composite component which is inherently already a naming container, but I personally recommend to stick to tagfile for this purpose.

#### See also:

- [How to make a grid of JSF composite component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713718/how-to-make-a-grid-of-jsf-composite-component)
- [Avoiding duplicate ids when reusing facelets compositions in the same naming container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552654/avoiding-duplicate-ids-when-reusing-facelets-compositions-in-the-same-naming-con/)
- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen)

Comment: Thank you for comprehensive answer. I liked the solution with <f:subview/> (less potentially needless declarations). I experimented with it, and I found that although "id" parameter is formally required, not declaring it causes that it gets automatically sequential value (like "j_idt129"). And this something what I was looking for (even though it can hamper identification of component).

Comment: You're welcome. For the tagfile you could also set `id` attribute to `<required>true</required>` in `taglib.xml`. IDEs will autoinsert the attribute on autocomplete. When the attribute is absent anyway, then it'll throw a tag exception during runtime when project stage is set to development. If you want to get a step further, checkout [OmniFaces `NoAutogeneratedIdViewHandler`](http://snapshot.omnifaces.org/viewhandlers/NoAutoGeneratedIdViewHandler).